# What's so special about primes $x^2+27y^2 = 31,43, 109, 157,\dots$ for cubics?

Tags: trigonometry, prime-numbers, roots-of-unity, cubics

While trying to find a closed-form solution for *particular* cubics as *sums of cosines* (related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068084/)), I came across this family with all roots real. Given a prime $p=6m+1$. Define,
$$F(x) = x^3+x^2-2mx+N =
\Big(x-2\sum_{k=1}^{m}\cos a\Big) \Big(x-2\sum_{k=1}^{m}\cos b\Big) \Big(x-2\sum_{k=1}^{m}\cos c\Big)=0$$
where,
$$a=2^k\times\beta,\;\;b=2^k\times3\beta,\;\;c=2^k\times m\beta,$$

and $\beta = \displaystyle\frac{2\pi}{p}$. I noticed that for certain primes, then $N$ ***is an integer***. The complete list for small $p$,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
p&N\\
\hline
31&  -8\\
43& 8\\
109&  -4\\
157&  64\\
223&  -256\\
229&  -212\\
277&  236\\
283&  304\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**Questions:**

1. What is the complete list of such primes for a low bound, say $p<3000$? (My old version of *Mathematica* conks out at $p>2000$.)
2. What do these primes $p$ have in common that make them distinct from other primes? (Other than that their $N$ is an integer.)
3. The coefficients of the cubic $F(x)=0$ are simple polynomials in $m$, except the constant term. Can $N$ be expressed as a polynomial in $m$?

**P.S.** I've checked the OEIS and it's not there, but the list I have for $p<2000$ suggests that a necessary (but not sufficient) condition is that

$$p = x^2+27y^2,\quad\text{and}\quad 2^{2m} = 1\;\text{mod}\;p$$

([A014752](https://oeis.org/A014752)) and ([A016108](https://oeis.org/A016108)), though it would be great if someone can prove (or disprove) that if $N$ is an integer, then these must hold.

Comment: "but not sufficient"... Do you know any prime $6n+1$ for which $2$ is a cubic residue that is not on your list?

Comment: ah: 127 is not in your list

Comment: The complete list for $p<2000$ is, $$p=31, 43, 109, 157, 223, 229, 277, 283, 691, 733, 739, 811, 1051, 1069, 1327, 1423, 1459, 1471, 1579, 1627, 1699, 1723, 1789, 1831, 1999.$$ They all obey $(1)$, though one can always turn up that doesn't.

Comment: All your primes are also expressible as $9 x^2 + 6 xy + 28 y^2. $ The set of (reduced) positive binary forms that represent, say, all three $31,43,109$ is finite and probably quite small. Worth seeing if one gets $157$ but misses $127$

Comment: Whoever figures this one out oughta send it in to Sloane's OEIS.

Comment: hmm i've just read this, but have you tried checking if those are the primes where $2$ generates the subgroup $H$ of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^*$ of index $3$ and where $3 \notin H$ ($3$ is not a cubic reidue) ?

Comment: @mercio: No. But I did notice that for prime $n=6m+1=x^2+27y^2$, if we define the sequence _T(c)=Table[Mod[c*2^n, 6m+1], {n, 0, m-1}]]_, then the elements of $T(2), T(6), T(2m)$ are _distinct_ and _disjoint_ apparently only for those $p$ in the list.

Comment: If my calculation is correct, the subsequent terms with $2000\leq p\leq 6000$ are: $2347$, $2749$, $2767$, $2791$, $2917$, $3163$, $3229$, $3259$, $3271$, $3463$, $3823$, $4027$, $4423$, $4519$, $4549$, $4567$, $4597$, $4651$, $4663$, $4759$, $4909$, $5101$, $5167$, $5413$, $5437$, $5503$, $5653$. They all seem to satisfy the condition (1).

Comment: @PeterKošinár: Thanks! OEIS has a list $L$ of primes up to c. 17700 that satisfy (1). I checked yours and they are all in $L$.

Comment: @mercio $p\in \{31, 223, 1327, 1423, \ldots\}$ do not seem to satisfy your condition, so it is not *necessary* -- but it seems to be *sufficient* based on my test so far. Perhaps it needs to be relaxed a bit?

Comment: @PeterKošinár: A more detailed version with related questions can be found in this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191184/).

Comment: "My old version of Mathematica conks out at $p>2000$". I assume you meant $p < 2000$?

Comment: @alexwlchan: I can take the calculation up to $p=2000$, but raising it to $p>2000$, and the software seems unstable.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Ah, I misread it. My bad, cheers.

Comment: @alexwlchan: And happy new year. My apologies about the 5th power calculation. The paper **did** say it was an open problem. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Question 1* was answered by Peter Kosinar in the comments, and a general version of *Question 2* was answered by Michael Stoll in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191184/).

The general case of *Question 3* is in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085973/).

**P.S.** One nice thing about these cubics is that, starting with Ramanujan's [general cubic identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1067992/4781), they are a special case, yielding the simple,

$$(a+b\,x_1)^{1/3}+(a+b\,x_2)^{1/3}+(a+b\,x_3)^{1/3}=\big(c+\sqrt[3]{dp}\big)^{1/3}$$

for some rational $a,b,c,d$. For example, using $p=109$, so $x^3 + x^2 - 36x - 4=0$, then,

$$(2+x_1)^{1/3}+(2+x_2)^{1/3}+(2+x_3)^{1/3}=\big({-19}+\sqrt[3]{4\cdot109}\big)^{1/3}=1.553389\dots$$