# "Casus irreductibilis"/"angle trisection" function

Tags: functions, numerical-methods

The resolution of the cubic equation is known to have a "casus irreductibilis" such that the computation of real roots requires an excursion in the complex numbers. The usual formulas involve trigonometric functions and essentially amount to the evaluation of

$$\cos\left(\frac{\arccos x+2k\pi}3\right)$$ which solves the angle trisection problem.

I would like to know if other formulations are known, which might be more computationally efficient.

---

The hyperbolic counterpart is

$$\cosh\left(\frac{\text{argcosh }x}3\right)=\cosh\left(\frac{\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}3\right)=\frac12\left(\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}+\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right).$$

---

**Update**:

By simple trigonometry, the function is in fact the three-branched inverse of the cubic $4x^3-3x$.

If a good approximate solution can be estimated, maybe a few Newton's iterations can quickly polish. The blue branch is close to

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{x+1}8}+\frac12.$$

[image]

Comment: yves, there is a distinction between the version you mention, with an arccos, and some cleaner versions which are sums of roots of unity, so that it becomes a sum of a small number of $2 \cos ( 2 \pi / k).$ Recently two kids asked about $x^3 + x^2 - 10 x - 8$ I think, let me find those; I made various comments on or related to those, so you could just look under my "all activity" under comments.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065862/something-strange-about-sqrt-4-sqrt-4-sqrt-4-x-x-and-its-friends#comment4072546_1065862

Comment: answer by Tito  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980175/how-would-you-find-the-trigonometric-roots-of-a-cubic/1983746#1983746

Comment: answer by mercio  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980693/finding-the-roots-of-any-cubic-with-trigonometric-roots/1982039#1982039

Comment: @WillJagy  Is there a general formula for $x\in\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: emphasize one point, in $x^2 + a x^2 + b x + c$ we may take an integer translation to alter $a$ by any multiple of $3.$ So, the cases can be $x^3 + x^2 + b x + c,$ then $x^3 + bx + c,$ then $x^3 - x^2 + bx + c.$ No important difference between first and third. Easy enough to compute a list with $|b|, |c| < 1000$ and the discriminant of $x^3 + x^2 + b x + c$ a square, which is how the Galois group becomes cyclic $\mathbb Z_3$

Comment: What for $\cos \left( (1/3) \arccos x \right)?$ I don't know.

Comment: @WillJagy: this is what my question is about (I tagged numerical methods).

Comment: I see. Well, proper I just left comments, then.

Comment: I am puzzled about the proper spelling, which was edited from *irreductibilis* to *irreducibilis*. If I am right, the adjective derives from *reducere*, *reductum*. The spelling *irreduciblilis* smells an English influence.

Comment: I've never seen it with a "t." You may have a point, though, Wantzel wrote irreductible  http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/NAM/NAM_1843_1_2_/NAM_1843_1_2__117_1/NAM_1843_1_2__117_1.pdf  Wonder what Cardano wrote, or Ruffini

Comment: @WillJagy: this is in French. The latin word is *irreductibilis*. https://books.google.be/books?id=buM2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA242&dq=casus+irreductibilis&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC9sOZ_vvPAhVSahoKHZjzAWsQ6AEIVDAH#v=onepage&q=casus%20irreductibilis&f=false

Comment: I see what you mean..by the time of Wantzel it had found its way into French with a "t," probably into other languages without a "t." Similar story to how the Gamma function is shifted one from the factorial. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20960/why-is-the-gamma-function-shifted-from-the-factorial-by-1/20962#20962

Comment: @WillJagy: from a little Web search, I see both spellings in Italian or German texts, and always without the 't' in English references.