# $\sqrt[3]{x_1} + \sqrt[3]{x_2} + \sqrt[3]{x_3} = \sqrt[3]{a},\,$ if $x_i$ are the real roots of $(x+b)^3 - a x^2$

Tags: polynomials, cubics, roots-of-cubics

Consider the equation,

$$(x+b)^3 = a x^2\tag1$$

with $a\ne 0$, and real roots $(x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3)$. Show that,

\begin{eqnarray}\sqrt[3]{x_1} &+& \ \sqrt[3]{x_2} &+ &\ \sqrt[3]{x_3} &=& \sqrt[3]{a}\\
\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x_1}}&+&\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x_2}}&+&\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x_3}}&=&\ 0
\end{eqnarray}

Notes:

1. Ramanujan had a series of equalities with cubic roots of trigonometric functions. The ones of second type  are of the form
   $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{\cos \frac{2 \pi}{7}}{\cos{ \frac{4 \pi }{7}} }}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{\cos \frac{4 \pi}{7}}{\cos{ \frac{6 \pi }{7}} }}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{\cos \frac{6 \pi}{7}}{\cos{ \frac{2 \pi }{7}} }}= \sqrt[3]{-7}$$
   since the above quotients of cosines are the roots of $x^3 + 4 x^2 + 3 x -1= (x-1)^3 - (-7) x^2$  One has  similar results considering $\cos$ of multiples of $\frac{2 \pi}{9}$.
2. There are general formulas for $(\sqrt[3]{x_1} + \sqrt[3]{x_2} + \sqrt[3]{x_3})^3$ being the root of a cubic polynomial with a unique real root, obtained in an algebraic way from the initial polynomial.  So   the above is on the beaten path. However, I did not find this  case  posted; it seems cute, and  easy to prove, so maybe useful as a reference.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

$\bf{Added:}$

1. We could also consider the cubic form
   $$(x+y)^3 -  x^2 z +  f x z ( x+y+ \frac{f^2}{27} z)$$
   Again, if the roots $x_i$ in $x$ are real and distinct then
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \sqrt[3]{x_1} + \ \sqrt[3]{x_2} + \ \sqrt[3]{x_3}=\sqrt[3]{z}
   \end{eqnarray}
2. One could try  something similar  for say $(x+b)^5 - a x^k$, $1\le k \le 4$, however the resulting equations do not have all roots real, since after taking the $5$-th root we get a polynomial with  gaps in coefficients.

Comment: @lone student: Yes, for the second statement, $b\ne 0$ also.

Comment: It's a strange world where this question gets downvoted.

Comment: @orangeskid: Your equation $(1)$ in fact has a LOT of interesting properties. I'll write a feedback within the hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\,\sqrt[3]{\cdot}\,$ is bijective on $\mathbb R\,$, for each real root $\,x_k= z_k^3\,$:

$$
(x_k+b)^3 - a x_k^2 = 0 \quad\iff\quad x_k + b = \sqrt[3]{a x_k^2} \quad\iff\quad z_k^3 + b =  \sqrt[3]{a}\,z_k^2
$$

Assuming $\,x_k\,$ are distinct, it follows that $\,z_k\,$ are the roots of $\,z^3 - \sqrt[3]{a}\, z^2 + b = 0\,$, so $\,\sum z_k = \sqrt[3]{a}$ and $\,\sum 1/z_k = 0\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\,$ To cover the remaining case of multiple roots, this happens iff $\,27 a^2 b^4 = 4 a^3 b^3\,$ (courtesy [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28%28x%2Bb%29%5E3+-+a+x%5E2%2C+3%28x+%2B+b%29%5E2+-+2+a+x%2C+x%29)). By the assumption that $\,ab \ne 0\,$ this leaves $\,27b=4a\,$, then the original cubic [becomes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=27%5E3+%28%28x%2Bb%29%5E3+-+a+x%5E2%29+where+b+%3D+4%2F27+a) $\,\frac{1}{27^3}(27 x - 8 a)^2 (27 x + a)\,$ with roots $\,x_k \in \{\frac{8a}{27},\frac{8a}{27},\frac{-a}{27}\}\,$, so $\,z_k \in \{\frac{2\sqrt[3]{a}}{3},\frac{2\sqrt[3]{a}}{3},\frac{-\sqrt[3]{a}}{3}\}\,$ which can be easily verified to satisfy both relations.

Comment: Great answer, very neat, thank you!  Btw, for the first equality, the only case to avoid is $a=0$, $b\ne 0$.

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks. Nice problem with some nice notes, btw. You are right, the $b=0$ case has roots $\{0,0,a\}$ which trivially satisfy the first equality. Granted, it's a bit inelegant to spend more explanation on the side cases than the main one, but I didn't see an easy way to avoid that here. Guess a continuity argument could have worked, but didn't want to hand-wave it either.

Comment: See what you think about a more general polynomial that I just added in the posting, it has an extra parameter $f$, and $y$, $z$ instead of $a$, $b$ ... :-)

Comment: @orangeskid Quite obviously, the shortcut here doesn't work for the second form. I am not sure that's any easier to solve than the general cubic, for which a $\sum\sqrt[3]{x_k}$ formula was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2885357), and for $\sum\sqrt[3]{u+x_k}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1067992). I may well be missing something, though, so consider posting that as a separate question, rather than an addendum which is easier to overlook.

Comment: So there Is a shortcut that generalizes this one here, as you noticed. Super!

Comment: @dxiv I see you linked to some old questions of mine. By the way, the first link finally has a quintic generalization. I'll get around to it soon. And the OP's simple cubic in this post turns out to have some very interesting properties. (Coincidentally, I was working on a similar cubic so I recognized it.)

Answer (score 4):

The OP asks for any feedback. In fact, the simple-looking cubic,

$$(x+\beta)^3 = \alpha x^2\tag1$$

has a **LOT** of interesting properties, being connected to *Ramanujan's theta function*, the *Klein quartic curve*, and *septic equations*. First, some minor transformations. Let $x = 1/y,\; \alpha=n^2+13n+49,$ and $\beta=1$ to get,

$$y^3+3y^2-(n^2+13n+46)y+1 = 0\tag{2a}$$

This retains the two properties mentioned by the OP, plus some additional ones. Given the [*Ramanujan theta function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function) $f(a,b)$, [*Dedekind eta function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) $\eta(\tau)$, and $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$, define,

\begin{align}
a &= -q^{61/168}\,\frac{f(-q,-q^6)}{f(-q^2)}\\
b &= \; q^{13/168}\;\frac{f(-q^2,-q^5)}{f(-q^2)}\\
c &= q^{-11/168}\,\frac{f(-q^3,-q^4)}{f(-q^2)}\\
n &= \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(7\tau)}\right)^4\\
\psi &= \left(\frac{\eta^3(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta^2(7\tau)}\right)^4
\end{align}

such that $(a,b,c)$ obey the [*Klein quartic curve*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KleinQuartic.html),

$$a^3b+b^3c+c^3a = 0$$

Then the roots $y_k$ of the cubic have the form,

\begin{align}
y_1 &= -(a^3b)^3\,\psi\\
y_2 &= -(b^3c)^3\,\psi\\
y_3 &= -(c^3a)^3\,\psi
\end{align}

which explains why the roots of,

$$y^3+3y^2-(n^2+13n+46)y+1 = 0\tag{2b}$$

even for **any** $n$ have,

$$y_1^{1/3} + y_2^{1/3} + y_3^{1/3} = 0$$

since they are just obeying the Klein quartic curve. However, if we take **7th** roots instead,

$$z=-(y_1^3\,y_2)^{1/7}-(y_2^3\,y_3)^{1/7}-(y_3^3\,y_1)^{1/7}\tag3$$

then $z$ is a solution *in radicals* to the solvable septic,

$$z^7 + 14 z^4 - 21 z^3 - 14 (46 + 13 n + n^2) z^2 - 7 (249 + 114 n + 18 n^2 + n^3) z - (1348 + 854 n + 207 n^2 + 23 n^3 + n^4) = 0$$

For example, let $n=-6$, then the septic,

$$z^7 + 14 z^4 - 21 z^3 - 56 z^2 + 21 z - 4 = 0$$

is solvable by the cubic,

$$y^3 + 3 y^2 - 4 y + 1 = 0$$

using the relation $(3)$ and the roots $y_k$ correctly ordered. There's more, but this is enough. And to think all these inter-connections came from the simple structure $(x+\beta)^3 = \alpha x^2.$

---

**Addendum**: Since the OP asked about the special functions $(a,b,c)$ of order 7 (more on these functions in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437994/using-the-rogers-selberg-identities-to-solve-certain-septics)), they are generalizations of the Roger-Ramanujan identities of order 5. Define,

\begin{align}
u &=\, q^{11/60}\,\frac{f(-q,-q^4)}{f(-q)}\; =\; q^{11/60}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\big(1-q^{5n-2}\big)\big(1-q^{5n-3}\big)}\\
v &= q^{-1/60}\,\frac{f(-q^2,-q^3)}{f(-q)} = q^{-1/60}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\big(1-q^{5n-1}\big)\big(1-q^{5n-4}\big)}
\end{align}

which now is related to the *quadratic*,

$$x^2-(m+11)x-1=0$$

with roots $(x_1, x_2) = (-u^{10}m^5,\;v^{10}m^5)$ and $m = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(5\tau)}\right)^6.$

---

**Radicals**

The eta quotients $(m,n,\psi)$ are radicals when $\tau = \sqrt{-d}$, which implies the special functions $(u,v)$ and $(a,b,c)$  are radicals are well. For example, let $d=1$, then,

\begin{align}
m &= \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(5\tau)}\right)^6 = 5^3\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^3\\ 
n &= \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(7\tau)}\right)^4 =\frac{28\times7^{3/4}\sqrt2}{\left(\sqrt{5-\sqrt7}-\sqrt{-7+3\sqrt7}\right)^2} \\
\psi &= \left(\frac{\eta^3(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta^2(7\tau)}\right)^4 =\frac{7^{3}\sqrt{14}}{\left(\sqrt{5-\sqrt7}-\sqrt{-7+3\sqrt7}\right)^4} \\
\end{align}

Substituting these into the quadratic and cubic, then solving for their roots, one can then solve for $(u,v)$ and $(a,b,c)$ in terms of radicals.

Comment: Thank you, a  beautiful answer! I have to look at it carefully

Comment: @orangeskid. This tied up with my recent research on roots of degree $p=3$ and $p=7$. I was pleasantly surprised the general form was so simple as $(x+\beta)^3 = \alpha x^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the rich context and unobvious angles!

Comment: Some mighty interesting things... how do you see ( for your equations) $\sum y_k^{-1/3}$ ( the connection with those amazing special functions). Now... those are real roots of order $7$ perhaps.   Also noticed that the discriminant is a square for the cubic depending on $n$.  Amazing stuff...

Comment: @orangeskid Yours was $\sum x_k^{-1/3}=0$ while mine was $\sum y_k^{1/3}=0$ so I knew both were related to the Klein quartic curve $a^3b+b^3c+c^3a=0.$ Yes, the discriminant of my cubic is a negative square, so it always has 3 real roots. And yes, those are roots of order 7, generalizing the Rogers-Ramanujan identities of order 5. Those three weird special functions, even with powers of $q^{1/168}$, are actually radicals if $\tau = \sqrt{-d}$. I'll add an example.