# $\sqrt[3]{x_1} + \sqrt[3]{x_2} + \sqrt[3]{x_3} = \sqrt[3]{z}$ if $x_i$ are the real distinct roots of $(x+y)^3 - x^2 z + f x z( x + y + f^2/27 z)$

Tags: cubics, roots-of-cubics

Show that

$$\sqrt[3]{x_1}+ \sqrt[3]{x_2} + \sqrt[3]{x_3} = \sqrt[3]{z}$$

where $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are the real distinct roots of a cubic polynomial in $x$  of the form

$$(x+y)^3 - x^2 z + f x z \left( x + y + \frac{f^2}{27} z\right)$$

Notes:

1. The form above is the most general possible.
2. For $f=0$ we get the [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673661/sqrt3x-1-sqrt3x-2-sqrt3x-3-sqrt3a-if-x-i-are-the-r) example, where @dxiv gave a neat [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673661/sqrt3x-1-sqrt3x-2-sqrt3x-3-sqrt3a-if-x-i-are-the-r/4673676#4673676).
3. One needs the discriminant of the above in $x$ to be positive. This implies $f\le 1$, so we can write $f = 1-u^2$.
4. One could write $z \mapsto 27 z$ to have integral coefficients.
5. Probably on the beaten path, reasonably cute, so posted  as a [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: objects in the mirror are closer than they appear

Comment: My mirror doesn't seem to work all that well tonight ;-) Thought I could reduce this to the previous form somehow, but ended up with a not-so-nice sextic along the way. Just curious, was this form based on algebraic or geometric insights?

Comment: @dxiv: Have you tried to solve for $y$ instead? :-)

Comment: Mirror still broken ;-) but I found another way. Hope you'll post your solution when all is said and done.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f=3t$ then the cubic is:

$$
p(x) = (x+y)^3 - x^2 z + t x z (3 x + 3 y + t^2 z) = \prod (x-x_k)
$$

Let $\omega$ be a primitive cube root of unity, and $q(x) = x^3 - u x^2 + v x - w$ the cubic with roots $\sqrt[3]{x_k}$, then:

$$
\begin{align}
q(x)\,q(\omega x)\,q(\omega^2x) &= \prod (x-\sqrt[3]{x_k})(\omega x-\sqrt[3]{x_k})(\omega^2x-\sqrt[3]{x_k})
\\ &= \prod (x^3 - x_k)
\\ &= p(x^3)
\end{align}
$$

It follows that:

$$
\begin{align}
p(x^3) &= (x^3 - u x^2 + v x - w)(x^3 - \omega^2\,u x^2 + \omega\, v x - w)(x^3 - \omega\,u x^2 + \omega^2\,v x - w)
\\ &= \color{blue}{x^9} - x^6 (u^3 - 3 u v + \color{blue}{3 w}) + x^3 (-3 u v w + v^3 + \color{blue}{3 w^2}) - \color{blue}{w^3}
\\ &= \color{blue}{(x^3-w)^3} - x^6 u^3 + x^3 \left(3 u v x^3 - 3u v w + v^3\right)
\end{align}
$$

By inspection, comparing to $\,p(x^3) = (x^3+y)^3 - x^6 z + x^3 (3 t z x^3 + 3 t z y + t^3 z^2)\,$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
u &= \sqrt[3]{z}
\\ v &= t \sqrt[3]{z^2}
\\ w &= -y
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore $\,q(x)=x^3 - \sqrt[3]{z}\,x^2 + t\sqrt[3]{z^2}\,x + y\,$, so $\,\sqrt[3]{x_1}+\sqrt[3]{x_2}+\sqrt[3]{x_3} = u = \sqrt[3]{z}\,$.

---

(***Note:*** *just for reference, below is the first and very different revision of my answer.*)

To get this out the way while looking forward to a more satisfying answer, the following is a brute force breakdown. With $f=3t$ the cubic is:

$$(x+y)^3 - x^2 z + t x z ( 3 x + 3 y + t^2 z) \;=\; x^3 + x^2 (3 y + 3 t z - z) + x (3 y^2 + 3 t y z + t^3 z^2) + y^3$$

@[River Li](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/584414/river-li)'s answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2885357/291201) provides a formula for $\,\sum \sqrt[3]{x_k}\,$ for generic cubics with distinct real roots (the assumption of rational coefficients is not needed or used AFAICT).

> In general, suppose $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the three distinct real roots of $x^3+bx^2+cx+d^3=0$,
> where $b,c,d$ are rational numbers. We have
> \begin{equation}
> \sqrt[3]{x_1}+\sqrt[3]{x_2}+\sqrt[3]{x_3} = \sqrt[3]
> {-\frac{3}{2}\Big(\sqrt[3]{Q+4\sqrt{\Delta}}+\sqrt[3]{Q-4\sqrt{\Delta}}\Big) -b-6d } \tag{*}
> \end{equation}
> where $Q = 24bd^2+36d^3+4bc+24cd, \Delta = -4b^3d^3-27d^6+18bcd^3+b^2c^2-4c^3$.
> Here, $\Delta$ is the discriminant of $x^3+bx^2+cx+d^3=0$.

With those notations, the cubic here has:

$$
\begin{align}
b &= 3 y + 3 t z - z
\\ c &= 3 y^2 + 3 t y z + t^3 z^2
\\ d &= y
\\ Q &= 4 (t z + 3 y) (3 t^3 z^2 - t^2 z^2 + 12 t y z + 18 y^2 - 3 y z) 
\\ \Delta &= -z^2 ((t - 1) t^2 z- y)^2 (t^2 (4 t - 1) z^2 + 2 (9 t - 2) y z + 27 y^2)
\\ Q^2 - 16 \Delta &= \big(4 (t^3 z^2 + (6 t - 1) y z + 9 y^2)\big)^3
\end{align}
$$

With the notations from my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4447889/291201) about denesting cube roots like  $\,\sqrt[3]{Q\pm4\sqrt{\Delta}}\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
r &= 4 (t^3 z^2 + (6 t - 1) y z + 9 y^2)
\\ s &= - t z - 3 y
\\ \sqrt[3]{Q+4\sqrt{\Delta}} + \sqrt[3]{Q-4\sqrt{\Delta}} = 2s &= -2(t z + 3 y)
\end{align}
$$

It follows that:

$$
{-\frac{3}{2}\Big(\sqrt[3]{Q+4\sqrt{\Delta}}+\sqrt[3]{Q-4\sqrt{\Delta}}\Big) -b-6d} = 3(t z + 3 y) - (3 y + 3 t z - z) -6y = z
$$

Which by $\,(*)\,$ concludes that $\,\sqrt[3]{x_1}+\sqrt[3]{x_2}+\sqrt[3]{x_3} = \sqrt[3]{z}\,$.

Comment: I am looking at the second solution and it is very close to mine... Neat!

Comment: @orangeskid Right, it's a slightly different path towards the same end.

Comment: I am starting to like your approach a lot.  Somehow solving the cubic is equivalent to factoring something of the form $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3 a b c$.

Comment: Yours is a better path, [look](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%5E3%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E3-3+a+b+c%2F.+%7Ba-%3E%28x%2By%29%2C+b-%3E+-x%5E%282%2F3%29z%5E%281%2F3%29%2C+c-%3E+g+x%5E%281%2F3%29+z%5E%282%2F3%29%7D)

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks. One nice thing about it is that the original cubic sorts of builds itself this way. WA helped with [$n=3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28x%29+f%28gx%29+f%28g%5E2x%29+-+%28x%5E3%2Bw%29%5E3+where+f%28x%29+%3D+x%5E3%2Bux%5E2%2Bvx%2Bw%2C+g+%3D+%28-1%2Bi+sqrt%283%29%29%2F2), and it returns something for $n=4$
 (which I haven't looked into more closely), but it chokes for $n \ge 5$. That remains for another question another day.

Answer (score 2):

Solving the equation for $y$ gets us

$$y = - x + x^{2/3} z^{1/3} - \frac{1}{3} f x^{1/3} z^{2/3}$$

and we are there...

(Guessable since the discriminant in $y$ has a  simple form.)

How to come up with such an equation?
Say we have a cubic equation for $t=x^{1/3}$. Then we can produce a cubic equation for $t^3$.  So start with an equation for $t$ with a given sum of roots and get, after  scaffolding removal, our form.

$\bf{Added:}$ @dxiv: showed us that the original expression is in fact

$$(x+y)^3 + (-x^{2/3} z^{1/3})^3 + (\frac{1}{3} f x^{1/3} z^{2/3})^3 - 3(x+y)(-x^{2/3} z^{1/3})(\frac{1}{3} f x^{1/3} z^{2/3})$$
so of the form $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3 a b c$

As a side note, one method of solving a cubic equation is reducing it to such a form.

Comment: looking at $x$ and $y$ is just behind...

Comment: Nicely done! I *almost* went there, but got discouraged too early ;-)

Comment: @dxiv: Thanks!  I got help with Mathematica,  solves for $y$  with a clean formula.