# How to prove $1+\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-4\cos^2 \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-8\cos^3 \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) \neq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

The task is to prove the following non-equality by hand:

> $$1+\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-4\cos^2 \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-8\cos^3 \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) \neq 0$$

Wolframalpha shows this, but I can't prove it.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bcos(2pi%2F7)-4cos%5E2(2pi%2F7)-8cos%5E3(2pi%2F7)%3D0

Comment: You don't need to prove sth you can just calculate it (as wolfram did) and see that it's false.

Comment: @MorphhproM Sure..Why not stop doing Math alltogether?

Comment: In my book its an identity but where i put on wolfram it says its false??

Comment: @MorphhproM He's asking how to see it without a calculator.

Comment: @Mongol-genius Your book was wrong. Wolframalpha is right. Or else you typed wrong.

Comment: @MXYMXY that's sth different

Comment: @MXYMXY yes because i cant prove it

Comment: There could be a typo. The "minimal polynomial" for $\cos(2\pi/7)$ is $1 + 4 x - 4 x^2 - 8 x^3$. So, if there were a $4$ on the $\cos(2\pi/7)$ term, you'd have an identity.

Comment: @MXYMXY i typed correct and i said it on question :)

Comment: @Mongol-genius: The typo might not be yours. Books make mistakes, too.

Comment: Make sure you notify the right person next time. I think that you should have notified Blue, not me.

Comment: @Blue yes you have right, but its anyway to prove its not equal to zero by hand, because the wolfram can do this and i can't thanks :)

Comment: I bet @Blue is right with his typo suggestion. Maybe you can find another book about your topic with the same equation or maybe the author pf your book uses the identity again and it's correct on another side or chapter

Comment: @Blue thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Mongol-genius, See : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225088/prove-that-frac14-sec22-pi-7-frac14-sec24-pi-7-frac?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

We prove a closely related result, which in particular shows there is a typo in the given equation.

The number $e^{2\pi i/7}$ is a root of $x^7=1$, and therefore of $x^6+x^5+\cdots+x+1=0$, or equivalently of
$$(x^3+x^{-3})+(x^2+x^{-2})+(x+x^{-1})+1=0.\tag{1}$$
(We divided through by $x^3$.) Let $w=\frac{1}{2}(x+x^{-1})$.

Note that $x^3 +x^{-3}=8w^3-6w$ and $x^2+x^{-2}=4w^2-2$ and $x+x^{-1}=2w$ So our equation can be rewritten as
$$8w^3+4w^2-4w-1=0.\tag{2}$$
Since $e^{2\pi i/7}$ is a root of (1), it follows that $\cos(2\pi/7)$ is a root of (2).

Comment: As always whole different approach $+1$

Comment: A whole different approach to what, @ArchisWelankar(I thought they used this often)? Anyway, +1.

Comment: Using complex numbers

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: What I wrote is one of the "standard" approaches.  One can bypass complex numbers by manipulating trigonometric identities, but that is structurally less nice, also much more work to type!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you please point me to the result guaranteeing that $e^{it}$ being a root guarantees that $cos(t)$ is also a root? It seems intuitively plausible but I don't remember ever proving such a result in my complex analysis course.

Comment: @K.Power That is not true in general. Notice the argument used shifts from talking about $x$ to talking about $w = \frac{x + x^{-1}}{2} = \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2} \equiv \cos(t)$. The last equation is in terms of $w$ not $x$.

Comment: Let $\theta=2\pi/7$.  Then $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$. I think this comes quite early, it is a direct consequence of the familiar identity $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.  Since $e^{i\theta}$ is a root of (1), and $w=\frac{1}{2}(x+x^{-1})$, it follows that $\cos\theta$ is a root of (2).

Comment: Is it a typo? By showing the equality of this equation, doesn't that imply the non-inequality given in the question?

Comment: Oh duh yes I completely forgot about that substitution by the end. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing prevents a statement of the problem with the given angle. Why necessarily a typo?

Comment: @Piquito: Compare the equation of my answer above with the equation of the question. If both were true, we would have $3\cos(2\pi/7)=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't think it does. The equation in the question is a **non-inequality**. Indeed, the value of that quantity in question is precisely $3 \cos (2 \pi / 7)$, which is non-zero, hence the non-equality holds.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: thanks for your comment. What I thought was that the question is true (if I am not wrong!) with that real angle. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Here, we will prove the equation by @AndreNicolas and @Blue in a more elementary manner.

> $$ 1+4\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-4\cos^2 \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-8\cos^3 \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) = 0 $$

Note that since $\cos 3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$, and since $\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1$, our equation simplifies to $$  \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right) -\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) + \cos \left(\frac{3\pi}{7}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Let $x=\frac{\pi}{7}$.

$$\cos x - \cos 2x + \cos 3x = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\cos x + \cos 3x + \cos 5x = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\cos x + \cos 3x + \cos 5x + ... = \frac{{\sin 2nx}}{{2\sin x}}$$
Since $n = 3$
$$\cos x + \cos 3x + \cos 5x = \frac{{\sin 6x}}{{2\sin x}}$$
$$\frac{{\sin 6x}}{{2\sin x}} = \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow \sin 6x = \sin x$$
Which is true since $\sin (\pi-x)=\sin x$.

Or,similarly if $$K=\cos x - \cos 2x + \cos 3x $$ then $$K\sin\frac{\pi}{7}=\frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}}{2}+\frac{\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}}{2}+\frac{\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}}{2}=\frac{\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}}{2}\implies K=\frac{1}{2}$$

Since $ 2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$

Comment: MXYMXY   Please correct the identities cos(3x) and cos(2x) and your answer :)

Comment: @Mongol-genius Does is work now?

Comment: MXYMXY  --I think after you have changed the identities your answer must change: your equation simplifies to cos(2pi/7)+cos(4pi/7)+cos(6pi/7)= -1/2

Comment: MXYMXY -  However Thanks for your essential solution :)

Comment: @Mongol-genius That simplifies to the equation above, using $\cos (\pi -x)=-\cos x$.

Answer (score 2):

Putting $x=\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})$ you have the polynomial $1+x-4x^2-8x^3\not= 0$ then $8x^3+4x^2-x-1\not=0$ from that
$$8x^3+4x^2-x-1=4x^2(2x+1)-x-1-x+x=4x^2(2x+1)-(2x+1)+x=(2x+1)(4x^2-1)+x=(2x+1)^2(2x-1)+x$$
Since $(2x+1)^2>0$ and $x>\frac{1}{2}$ since $\frac{2\pi}{7}<\frac{\pi}{3}$ we have that $(2x-1)>0$ and a sum of positive numbers isn't zero.

Answer (score 2):

I will address the problem as it has been stated not as to whether there is a conjectured or assumed typo.

First off the problem is equivalent to showing

$$\frac{(1+\zeta)}{\zeta^{2}(1+2\zeta)}\neq4$$ where $\zeta=cos(2\pi/7)$.

Since $1/2\lt\zeta\lt1$, the left hand side of the inequality is less than $3$ and therefore we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $p(x)=1+x-4x^2-8x^3$, that have only one real root, $x_0\approx0,4$. Now, calculating $x=\cos(2\pi/7)\approx0,6$ we find that $x\neq x_0$

Comment: You are asked to prove the non-equality by hand. If you meant for these approximations to be computed by hand, then please indicate this together with (a sketch of) a method of finding this approximation _by hand_.

Comment: Because is continuous, I apply Bolzano+ bisection

Comment: You also have to compute the cosine. Either way, this is supposed to be in your answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

We consider $$f(x) = x - 4x^2 - 8x^3  $$

Notice that for $x \ge \frac{1}{2}, \>\> f(x) < -1$ siince $f(\frac{1}{2}) = -\frac{3}{2} $ and $f'(\frac{1}{2}) < 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x > -1$

Now it's only important to show that $\cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} \ge \frac{1}{2}$

It should be relatively easy to show $\cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} \ge \cos \frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Please Include a proof of why $x \ge \frac{1}{2}, \>\> f(x) < -1$, and In your answer, not a comment.